# pipenv python upgrade no such file

Tags: homebrew, upgrade, pipenv

I recently upgraded from python 3.6 to 3.7. I'm on osx and had installed pipenv previously following their instructions.
I updated my python to 3.7 (don't remember exactly how) and now when I'm in a virtualenv I see the error

```
$ jupyter lab
zsh: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: no
such file or directory
```

my path

```
/Users/harrymoreno/.local/share/virtualenvs/DLwP-ZqM5COLn/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/.yarn/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
/usr/local/go/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/.nix-profile/bin
/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/programming/google-cloud-sdk/bin
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.1/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin
/Applications/FirefoxDeveloperEdition.app/Contents/MacOS
/Users/harrymoreno/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/harrymoreno/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
/Users/harrymoreno/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/bin
```

this is not jupyter lab specific, I see it with django as well. What might the cause and how should one properly upgrade their python on osx?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `pyenv`. This is a Python version manager, similar to ruby `rvm`. You can get it by `brew install pyenv`. Then you could upgrade your Python using:

`pyenv install <Python version you want>` and `pyenv uninstall <old version>`

So in your case: `pyenv install 3.7.0`and `pyenv uninstall 3.6.x`

The reason for the old version reference could be an error in your path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another thing could be the virtualenv in `/Users/harrymoreno/.local/share/virtualenvs/DLwP-ZqM5COLn/bin`. virtualenv usually makes a full copy of your Python Interpreter in this directory. If you upgraded the systemwide Python version, this should not influence your Python Interpreter in this directory. I'd try this: `cd into this directory` and then `./python --version` .